# Angular 4 Unsafe value used in Resource URL

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have following code to display pdf file.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
    {
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResoureUrl('./uploads/{file.filename}}');
    } 

<object data="./uploads/{{file.filename}}" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

When this runs I get error

```
Error: unsafe value used in a Resource URL Context
```

I went through other posts here and implemented the constructor bypass solution still same error.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use SafeResourceUrl in data attribute. This method should work:

Add a method to your component:

```
getSafeUrl(fileName) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("./uploads/" + fileName);
    }
```

And change your html:

```
<object [data]="getSafeUrl(file.fileName)" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

So you can remove your code in constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you .?

```
public url: any;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
    {
        this.url = './uploads/{file.filename}}';
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResoureUrl(this.url);
    } 

<object data="url" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

Comment: This code won't work, the method name has a typo, `url` is not binded with `[data]`, `{file.filename}` is not replaced,...